Не могу сделать комит на переименованой ветке гита
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Drag0nXLR/easy_editor.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Мне показывает эту ошибку всякий раз, когда я хочу сделать push

Ну там же написано, что в ветке есть изменения, которых нет у вас локально, поэтому нужно сначала сделать pull, а потом уже push.

Спасибо за помощь!
